# Django forms processing dynamic field labels

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I've made a form that gets built dynamically depending on a parameter passed in, and weight classes stored in the database. This all works fine (note: it's not a ModelForm, just a Form).

Now I'm trying to save the user's responses. How can I iterate over their submitted data so I can save it?

There is a similar question located here: [Processing dynamic MultipleChoiceField in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537788/processing-dynamic-multiplechoicefield-in-django)

I can't get it to work for me though, as my situation is slightly different. I want to see the label of the option button that the user has selected in the form and compare that value as it will match the value of a weight class already stored in the database. The form contains fields such as 'first_name' and 'last_name' and the code that I use to dynamically generate the weight classes is as follows:

```
def __init__(self, event, *args, **kwargs):
    super(EntryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    groups = ClassGroup.objects.all()
    weight_classes = ClassOrder.objects.filter(event=event).order_by('weight')
    current_group = regclasses[0].competition_class.class_group

    for weight_class in weight_classes.all():
        self.fields['%s' % weight_class.competition_class.class_group.group_name] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[ (o.id, o.class_name + ": " + o.class_info) for o in weight_class.competition_class.class_group.classes_in_group.all()], widget=forms.RadioSelect(), label=weight_class.competition_class.class_group.group_name, required=False)
```

This gives me something like:

Men's Weight Classes

- Men's Lightweight
- Men's Middleweight
- Men's Lightheavyweight
- Men's Hevyweight
- Men's Superheavyweight

in addition to the form fields that aren't dynamically generated.

Which are all part of a RadioSelect group. I'm attempting to process the form using the following code:

```
for field in form.fields:
    if Classes.objects.filter(class_name=field).count > 0: #checking to see if the field's name matches a class

    newentry = Entry(
        athlete = athlete,
        event = event,
        athlete_class = Classes.objects.filter(class_name=field)
        )
```

The idea is that the for loop should iterate the fields in the form and check if the field's label is the same as a weight class in the database. If the field and the weight class in the database match then a new entry is created with the athlete, the event, and the weight classes that the athlete has selected in the form. When the code is run, I get the error

**Cannot assign "[]": "Entry.athlete_class" must be a "Classes" instance.**

My guess is that the 'field' variable isn't referencing the label of the option button. How do I get the form to process the name of the weight class that is dynamically generated?

Comment: Looks likes you don't have any ```Classes``` where ```class_name```= field in your database. So your ```filter``` returns an empty list and it blows up.

Comment: Yes, there are weight classes where the class_name matches the label of the field. I know this because the labels for the option buttons on the form are dynamically generated from the weight classes in the database. I want to know which weight classes the user has picked on the form and save that in the entry as a foreign key in the Entry model in the database.

Comment: `count` is a _method_, you need to call it: `if Classes.objects.filter(class_name=field).count():`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Classes.objects.filter(class_name=field)
```

returns a queryset, but you want a Classes instance.

```
Classes.objects.get(class_name=field)
```

will do that.

Comment: Thanks. That helped out a lot, but now I get the error **Classes matching query does not exist. Lookup parameters were {'class_name': 'first_name'}**. I'm guessing that it's looking at the first field in the form named 'first_name' that's not dynamically generated (which was omitted for readability's sake). I believed that the 'if' statement should have filtered out the fields that don't match the weight class names in the database. How do I only process the dynamically generated fields?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this previously by creating an array attached to the form with the dynamically generated fields and then just iterate over that.

Alternatively you could put the objects.get(...) in a try/except block:

```
try:
    Classes.objects.get(class_name=field)
except:
    pass
else:
    newentry = Entry(
        athlete = athlete,
        event = event,
        athlete_class = Classes.objects.filter(class_name=field)
        )
```

The reason why the if statement doesn't work is that the following block is not indented correctly. This should work also (note the parenthesis after the count):

```
if Classes.objects.get(class_name=field).count() > 0:
    newentry = Entry(
        athlete = athlete,
        event = event,
        athlete_class = Classes.objects.filter(class_name=field)
        )
```

Comment: Hi, did this help? If yes, I wouldn't mind having this answer marked as the correct answer. Thanks.